# Shift key remain pressed even after the script is closed

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote this code to remap some of my kepad keys to Alt, Shift, Control keys. The problem is that the shift key remain 
 pressed when I release  Numpad1 and even after I closed the script

```
Numpad0::send {Control down}
Numpad0 Up::send {Control Up}
Numpad1::send {Shift down}
Numpad1 Up::send {Shift Up}
NumpadDot::send {Alt down}
NumpadDot Up::send {Alt Up}
```

Comment: See [**Remapping Keys**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually re-mapping keys, but creating entirely new functions for them. See [re-mapping keys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) if you want to go that path. All you're doing right now is sending tons of looping instructions to press the shift key down, and then one instruction to release it. Coupled with the fact that [the numpad keys have different behaviour states](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#numpad), you're just asking for trouble.